# How to label cells in a square grid

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I am relatively new to Tikz and there are still many aspects of it which I am unfamiliar with. I would like to construct the following diagram as appended in the picture. Now, I do know how to create the square grid itself, but I don't know how to label the individual squares as required in my diagram.

Edit: The code for the 8 by 8 grid is simply this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[step=1cm,black,very thin] (-2,-2) grid (6,6);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Thanks in advance for any help rendered.[image: Diagram]

Edit 2: Thanks to the accepted answer, I now understand the code that is needed to construct what I wanted. Here it is in its entirety:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of nodes, nodes={minimum size=1cm, draw, anchor=center}, row sep=-\pgflinewidth, column sep=-\pgflinewidth](mygrid){%
 R & B & W & G & R & B & W & G \\
 B & W & G & R & B & W & G & R \\
 W & G & R & B & W & G & R & B \\
 G & R & B & W & G & R & B & W \\
 R & B & W & G & R & B & W & G \\
 B & W & G & R & B & W & G & R \\
 W & G & R & B & W & G & R & B \\
 G & R & B & W & G & R & B & W \\
 };
 \end{tikzpicture}
```

Edit 3: Here is another solution provided in one of the replies, which uses modular arithmetic - which I believe is powerful since it generalizes to arbitrarily large squares, without us having to manually input the value of each cell:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\edef\lstM{"R","B","W","G"}
\path (-1.5,6) coordinate(m10);
\foreach \X in {1,...,8}
{\foreach \Y in {1,...,8}
{\pgfmathsetmacro{\pft}{{\lstM}[Mod(\X+\Y-2,4)]}
\ifnum\X=1
\node[draw,minimum size=1cm,anchor=north] (m\X\Y) 
at ([yshift=\pgflinewidth]m\X\the\numexpr\Y-1.south){\pft};
\else 
\node[draw,minimum size=1cm,anchor=west] (m\X\Y) 
at ([xshift=-\pgflinewidth]m\the\numexpr\X-1\relax\Y.east){\pft};
\fi}}
\draw[black, solid]  (-2,-2) grid (6,6); 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Where I changed [red, dashed] to [black, solid] just to fit my purposes.

Comment: Hi @ONG SEE HAI and [welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436). In its current form, your question might not receive many answers. Please take a look at the [How to Ask](//tex.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)-page and try to improve your question according to the guidance found there. This may require you to show some effort on your part in terms of attempting a solution. If you have questions about what to do or if you don't quite understand what this means, please ask for clarification using the `add comment` function.

Comment: Hello, the problem is as mentioned in my post... I do know how to construct the grid, but I have completely no idea about how to label the individual squares.

Comment: You can still show us how you constructed the grid.  That may inform some of the suggestions on how to populate the grid.

Comment: @Steven B. Segletes Thanks, I have added it! See the post.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/533485/134144 is similar.

Comment: @leandriis, I am sorry, but how do we modify the code to suit this case because it is different in the sense that the square in my situation has well-defined boundaries?

Comment: Remove the `\draw [black] (table-1-1.north west)...` and add `draw=black` as in: `nodes={anchor=center,
         minimum width=1.25cm, 
         minimum height=1.25cm, 
         draw=black
         },`.

Comment: Thank you! Will give it a shot now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here you have something to start with:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of nodes, nodes={minimum size=1cm, draw, anchor=center}, row sep=-\pgflinewidth, column sep=-\pgflinewidth](mygrid){%
R & B & W & G \\
B & W & G & R \\
W & G & R & B \\
G & R & B & W \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun. Using some modulo arithmetic.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \edef\lstM{"R","B","W","G"}
 \path (-1.5,6) coordinate(m10);
 \foreach \X in {1,...,8}
  {\foreach \Y in {1,...,8}
  {\pgfmathsetmacro{\pft}{{\lstM}[Mod(\X+\Y-2,4)]}
  \ifnum\X=1
   \node[draw,minimum size=1cm,anchor=north] (m\X\Y) 
   at ([yshift=\pgflinewidth]m\X\the\numexpr\Y-1.south){\pft};
  \else 
   \node[draw,minimum size=1cm,anchor=west] (m\X\Y) 
   at ([xshift=-\pgflinewidth]m\the\numexpr\X-1\relax\Y.east){\pft};
  \fi}}
 \draw[red,dashed]  (-2,-2) grid (6,6); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The red grid is just to guide the eye.

Comment: Wonderful, thanks! I think your method is more powerful since it allows the generalization to an arbitrarily large grid without actually having to manually input the entry for each cell.